# How input data in line chart in Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I want to make this chart in Pentaho CDE:
[image]

based in this chart (I think that is the most similar from among CCC Components): 
[image]
(The code is in this [link](https://webdetails.github.io/ccc/#type=line&anchor=line-plots-with-5-number-statistics-as-series).)

but I don't know how I can adapt my data input to that graph.
For example, I want to consume the data with this format:

> **[Year, customers_A, customers_B, cars_A, cars_B] 
> [2014, 8, 4, 23, 20]**
> **[2015, 20, 6, 30, 38]**

How I can input my data in this chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data should come as an object such as this:

```
data = {
  metadata: [
    { colName: "Year", colType:"Numeric", colIndex: 1},
    { colName: "customers_A", colType:"Numeric", colIndex: 2},
    { colName: "customers_B", colType:"Numeric", colIndex: 3},
    { colName: "cars_A", colType:"Numeric", colIndex: 4},
    { colName: "cars_B", colType:"Numeric", colIndex: 5}
  ],
  resultset: [
    [2014, 8, 4, 23, 20],
    [2015, 20, 6, 30, 38]
  ],
  queryInfo: {totalRows: 2}
}
```

Comment: Where can I get this format data for other charts?

Comment: Format is always the same for all charts. This is the output from Pentaho CDA. There's always a metadata array with column info; a queryInfo object, and a resultset as an array, each element of which is a row of data.